# Navigation Bar's Button Item Not Clickable on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my app, I use the old GKImage library for adding pictures and being able to custom crop them easily. This works pretty well, except when it comes to iPad. On iPhone, everything works great. The main issue is this:

When I use an iPad, none of the barButtonItems are clickable.

Here is my code for this view:

```
- (void)_actionCancel{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)_actionUse{
    NSLog(@"PRESSED");
    _croppedImage = [self.imageCropView croppedImage];
    [self.delegate imageCropController:self didFinishWithCroppedImage:_croppedImage];
}


- (void)_setupNavigationBar{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                          target:self 
                                                                                          action:@selector(_actionCancel)];
    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Use"
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                             target:self 
                                                                             action:@selector(_actionUse)];
}


- (void)_setupCropView{
    
    self.imageCropView = [[GKImageCropView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.imageCropView setImageToCrop:sourceImage];
    [self.imageCropView setResizableCropArea:self.resizeableCropArea];
    [self.imageCropView setCropSize:cropSize];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageCropView];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma Super Class Methods

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.title = @"Choose Photo";

    [self _setupNavigationBar];
    [self _setupCropView];

    
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    
}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    
    self.imageCropView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

The code used to present this controller is:

```
self.imagePicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(280, 280);
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is it an issue with presenting the view controller?

Comment: This `self.imageCropView.frame = self.view.bounds;` seems suspect. Can you tap the bar button if you ***don't*** add `imageCropView` to the view?

Comment: @DonMag no, it still can’t be tapped. And it works fine on iPhone, so is so weird